# Why are some questions a different color on the screen?

Tags: support

Why do some questions show up in a different color box on the screen and some are just white?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cropped off the answer to your question. Let me explain.

Look over at the sidebar under the heading "Favorite Tags." Those are tags you have marked as your favorites. SE then highlights any question tagged with one of them.

This how it looks for me (you have different tags marked as your favorite).
[image: BSE home page with Favorite Tags highlighted]

So to answer your question it is because you have [modifiers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifiers) as one of your favorite tags, and SE highlights questions that are tagged with one of your favorites.